# AES Keys Storage for encrypting hashes of SAM file in Windows 10

Tags: hash, aes, windows-10

Hashes of user account passwords in Windows 10 (like in older versions) are stored in SAM file. Using standard utility pwdump 7 for getting these hashes gives following result:

::LM hash : NTLM hash

But these hashes are encrypted with AES 128. I wonder where I can found AES keys for encrypting these hashes and how I can retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

The AES Key to decrypt the Double Encrypted Hash is derived from the “SysKey”, which is in itself also AES encrypted.

Comment: I use mimikatz; get necessary privilege and after command lsadump::sam I have a table where there are SysKey and SAMKey values. I 've tried to use them like decryption key for AES-128 ECB but they have brought me "wrong" hashes. Is SysKey encrypted on som master key? And how can I derive right value of encryption key AES 128?

Comment: SysKey is AES encrypted with Bootkey.

Comment: can you write please, how can I decrypt it?

Comment: Bootkey is calculated by reordering the 4 Class Names from JD, Skew1, GBG and Data

Comment: I've answered your initial question.

Comment: Hm... still unclear. Can you write where I can find the value of this Bootkey? May be some program or something like that..?

Comment: I don't think that answering any of further questions will help you. Your initial question should be: "How to decrypt Windows 10 sam hashes" then someone could point you to this [link](http://www.insecurity.be/blog/2018/01/21/retrieving-ntlm-hashes-and-what-changed-technical-writeup/#New_Style_Hash_Retrieval)

Are you planning on up voting my answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course I am! Shall I answer the new one question about decryption in another topic?